# Testflight build on Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I want to upload my Testflight build to apple Appstore so that i can get the crash logs from users and fix them before releasing the next builds.

But i am not sure if i can get the logs from app on Testflight from Appstore build.
On Testflight it is mentioned that we can use the Testflight to get the crash logs from Appstore build as well. But i want to make sure that i will get as much crash logs as i can on Testflight.

I tried the same thing on my own by uploading a build on Testflight and than installing the build on my iPad which i uploaded on the testflight.

But i never recieves any logs on testflight for my build.

But if i Install the same build from Testflight than only i get the logs on testflight.

so i am bit confused if Testflight logs actually works on the Appstore build as well.

If anyone has done this earlier please guide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this indeed works. I've used this just yesterday with my App during it's launch.

Steps I followed:

1. Creative an archive of the project.
2. Submit to the App Store using this Archive.
3. Create an Ad-hoc build (.ipa file) using the exact same Archive.
4. Upload the Ad-hoc build to Testflight. It should automatically detect the DYSM for this.
5. Once you're live on the App Store, and if the app crashes, you'll see it's symbolicated crash report on Testflight (under that particular build of the app).

So make sure you use the same archive, same build number, etc. and you'll be good to go.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand your point "It should automatically detect the DYSM for this." as per i understand we have to separately upload the .dsym zip file to testflight as it never automatically detects the DYSM file..

Comment: Also as per your comments testflight should show all logs for the build uploaded from same archieve. But while testing i used the same build which i uploaded to testflight. but it never shows any logs on Testflight for that. Is there any difference?

Comment: You won't receive all logs. Only crash logs. So none of your NSLog statements will show up. For that, take a look at services that couple with CocoaLumberjack.

Comment: sorry i was not able to explain my question properly.. Actually i have not seen any "TestFlight passCheckpoint:" logs (not NSLog) also I crashed my application on a known crashpoint but it still never shows up on testflight..

Comment: It may take sometime for the crashlogs to show up on Testflight. Also, try running your app locally to confirm that the App properly registers the TF Token. 

Make sure you don't have any other crash handlers in place. If you include TF, it atomically sets up it's own crash handles when you call `takeOff:`. 

Last but not the least: `passCheckpoint` logs only work with Ad-Hoc and dev builds. On Production builds, only the crash handlers will work. Nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for such useful information.. I will test my builds again and check how it works..

Comment: 1 more confusion do we have to manually disable the passCheckpoint logs or it will be disabled automatically in Appstore build.

Comment: It's disabled Automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to use **Bugsense** https://www.bugsense.com/ to get the **crash logs**. Its free version is good enough for most app. If you are willing to pay, with a few simple steps, it can help you to symbolize the crash logs (that are hard to understand) to become readable.

Comment: unfortunately we are tightly coupled with testflight and doesn't want to use anyother tool or library now so looking for a solution for testflight only.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Just sharing.